# useEffect wont work on conditional change when still in execution of async function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

On a page load I have two useEffects. Both are executing at load, where the first one can possibly set a state, that should trigger the second useEffect one further time. But actually it won't.

Actually it should trigger, as it executes in two cases: When i change the order of these useEffects (could be a solution, but why???), or when i comment out the `void getOrPostOnWishlist();`, thus when removing the async call from the useEffect. But why is that a problem here?

Here some example code snippet with some comments:

```
...

const setItemIdToBeHandled = (itemId: number | undefined) =>
  setState((prevState) => ({...prevState, itemIdToBeHandled: itemId}));

...

// async, called on second useEffect
const getOrPostOnWishlist = async () => {
  if (state.itemIdToBeHandled) {
    // if there is an item to be handled, retrieve new wishlist with added item
    await addItemToNewWishlist(state.itemIdToBeHandled);
  } else if (!state.wishlist) {
    // if no wishlist is locally present, check if wishlist exists on api
    await checkForPresentWishlist();
  }
};

// possibly setting state
React.useEffect(() => {
  const urlItemId = UrlSearchParamsHelper.wishlistItemId;
  if (urlItemId) {
    console.log("found item id in url:", urlItemId);
    setItemIdToBeHandled(urlItemId);
  }
}, []);

// on state change, but also on load
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log("condition:", state.itemIdToBeHandled); // sticks on 'undefined'
  void getOrPostOnWishlist(); // when commented out, above console will show 'undefined', and then an itemId (considering the first useEffect sets the state);
}, [state.itemIdToBeHandled]);
```

This led to the following output:

[image: Where is the missing useEffect]

But when just commenting out the async call in the second useEffect, this led to:

[image: Why is there a missing useEffect]

Googled around, and also tried useCallback, but that didn't work. Doesn't seem to be the issue here, since it's somewhat not about the content of the called function, but about the very fact, that the calling useEffect is not even executed.

It feels like even without await inside the useEffect, a useEffect is still blocked, when it has executed an async function.

Or am i missing something? If some more details are needed, let me know

Comment: I think you should remove void from "void getOrPostOnWishlist();" and things work as you want

Comment: Nope, didn't make a change. Besides the fact that ESLint complains
(@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises)

Comment: Where are you getting `state` from?  It's strange you're accessing it manually rather than through a `useSelector` if that's a redux state.

Comment: Actually it's no redux, but 'redux-alike'.
But actually you brought me to the solution. Had a closer look to the state handling, and found out, there was another setState deeper in the `checkForPresentWishlist()`, that reset the `itemIdToBeHandled` to the initial/default _undefined_, that seems to be done slower than/after the first useEffect sets anything.

Comment: So the conditional array of the second useEffect doesn't have any change to execute it.
Will further investigate on this